# typescript type for single and array properties

Tags: typescript

I have following use case for TypeScript types:

I have a certain interface, e.g:

```js
interface Data {
 a: number;
 b: string;
}
```

and I need these interfaces:

```js
interface DataSingleValue {
 a: number;
 b: string;
}
interface DataArrayValue {
 a: number[];
 b: string[];
}
```

So the interfaces do have all properties of the `Data`-interface with the same data type. Just in one case they are all arrays.

I have a lot of such interfaces and I would like to have something like this:

```js
interface Model<T | T[]> {// dont know how to do}

interface DataSingleValue extends Model<Data> {} --> leads to the same as above
interface DataArrayValue extends Model<Data[]> {} -> leads to the same as above
```

How to do this?

Comment: Very probably with [Mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html)

Comment: like this? https://tsplay.dev/w24Lbm

Comment: @Thomas that is exactly what I need! thank you! :) If you might want to post it as answer then I can mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: @Thomas plz make the answer, I will not have time to do any